# Tensorflow, errors with dataset: "Cannot convert a DataFrame into a Tensor or Operation."

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I am trying to create a Neural Network with Tensorflow and I am trying to use a pandas dataframe as my data. This gives me an error saying that I cannot convert a dataframe into a Tensor. I thought that passing the dataframe through `numpy.asarray()` should have fixed this error but I still get the error.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
dataframe.drop(dataframe.columns.difference(["Happiness.Score", "Freedom", "Family", "Generosity"]), 1, inplace=True)

train = dataframe[1:11]
test = dataframe[12:22]

test.pop("Happiness.Score")

dataY = np.asarray(train["Happiness.Score"])
dataX = np.asarray(train.drop(["Happiness.Score"], axis=1))

inputX = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10, 3])
inputY = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(inputX, W) + b)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(inputY))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(.01)
trainer = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for step in range(1000):
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={inputX: dataX, inputY: dataY})
    print(sess.run(cross_entropy, feed_dict={inputX: dataX, inputY: dataY}))
sess.close()
```

This throws the error

> has invalid type , must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a DataFrame into a Tensor or Operation.)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to use this line ?

```
    sess.run(trainer, feed_dict={inputX: dataX, inputY: dataY})
```

You are using this line now.

```
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={inputX: dataX, inputY: dataY})
```